# Did Mete Khan and Hsiung-nu serve the Chinese Emperor?

Tags: international-relations, ancient-china, asia, steppe-nomads

I was reading Nicolae Jorga's "History of Ottoman Empire vol. 1" and he gave information that Mete Khan, who freed Hsiung-nu people from the rule of Yue-chi, was a servant of the Chinese Emperor. But at the bottom of the page there is an editorial note saying, "During the time of Mete Khan, Huns were not serving China".

Common sense dictates that Mete Khan is, of course he wasn't serving China but from where did Jorga have the idea?

Comment: Is this all that he says about it? Could he be talking about a very early time, c. 210, or during wars with the Yuezhi c. 170? Providing more info would help because the book is in Turkish.

Comment: @congusbongus have you found the passage in question? Can you translate it?

Answer (score 0):

The current Wikipedia entry for the Yue-chi depicts them as being mostly [friendly trading partners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuezhi#Origins) with the Chinese. The (likely Turkish) Xiongnu empire built by the victorious [Modu Chanyu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modu_Chanyu) (aka: Mete Khan, or "Brave Khan" in Turkish), was [anything but](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiongnu#War_with_Han_Dynasty).

It wouldn't be too surprising to find that histories sourced mostly from the victorious Turks are a bit dismissive of the losers. Relatively friendly trading relations would be just enough of a germ of truth to build the story around.

Comment: In fact, there are no sources coming from Turks during that era. The very first historical resource we have is 12nd century. So literally all of the historical records about Yue-chi, Hsiung-nu and all other tribes are from Chinese chronicles. So your statement about information sourced mostly from the victorious Turks are historically wrong since we have none. My question was not if Mete Khan was in service of China or not. I wonder what pushed Nicolae Jorga to develop that idea? Since he is a great historian.

Comment: @MertÇelikok I think you are simply misreading the text. The text does not imply that Modu Chanyu was serving China; it implies that the "Huns" were at some point.

Comment: @congusbongus Can you please refer to the page/paragraph which you are deducing this from the book?

Comment: @MertÇelikok : It would be useful if you also added the parts of this work that you are alluding to in quotes in the body of the question...

Answer (score -2):

Mete Khan (HAN) was the only Turkic ruler of China . He beat China and its colossal army with 300.000 with 40.000 soldiers.
What people don't realize is that the Turks history goes back 6 to 7000 years. Turks religion was Tnengrism and shamanism which is oldest religion  of the world. The Chinese built the Great China Wall to protect themselves  from Turkish attacks & it took them 2200 years to complete the whole wall with different dynasties considering Chinese history goes back only 3000 years. If you can access the Chinese history archives it will reveal the answer to this. Because Turks always been nomadic people never stayed one particular place alone but always different parts of the geography in the regions and has no written  books but carved stone pillars.  *[Wikipedia:
Orkhon_inscriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orkhon_inscriptions)*

Comment: -1 : Beside its many controversial claims, this "answer" doesn't attempt to address the question.